# Newly added images not rendering .NetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry if this seems like a silly question, but for some reason my ASP Web Application won't show images that I have saved in my /wwwroot/images folder. The only images that show are any images I use for the default carousel and logo, otherwise nothing appears even with the same code.
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEqF4.png)

And I am calling for the image here:
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAKnB.png)

So all the images which start with "advert: don't work because I recently added them. The rest do.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1 - Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MinResApp.Data;
using MinResApp.Models;
using MinResApp.Services;

namespace MinResApp
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDbContext<MinresContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();



        services.AddMvc();
    }
    //Adds additional User Roles to the system
    private async Task CreateUserRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();


        IdentityResult roleResult;
        IdentityResult roleResult2;
        IdentityResult roleResult3;
        //Adding Admin Role  
        var roleCheck = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
        if (!roleCheck)
        {
            //create the roles and seed them to the database  
            roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
        }

        //Adding Admin Role  
        var roleCheck2 = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Trader");
        if (!roleCheck2)
        {
            //create the roles and seed them to the database  
            roleResult2 = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Trader"));
        }

        //Adding Admin Role  
        var roleCheck3 = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Investor");
        if (!roleCheck3)
        {
            //create the roles and seed them to the database  
            roleResult3 = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Investor"));
        }

    }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider services)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try to publish youe application and chek if they're copied or not

Comment: I am unable to publish at the moment. But surely they should load? I can change images on my carousel for example.

Comment: Can you post your `Startup.cs` content

Comment: Try to Clean you solution (Build > Clean Solution), rebuild it and check again.

Comment: I added my Startup.cs

Comment: @MajdiSaibi Clean and build did not work.

Comment: Where are you calling the image?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to figure it out a few days ago. Not 100% sure what the issue was but an element style was being added to the div where the image was supposed to rendered in and making it hidden. I would advise anyone else who gets an error like this just to inspect the CSS to see if there is any generated element styles. Just as a first form of trouble shooting.

Thanks for all the help. Learned a lot.